# li высота на одном уровне

Tags: css

Бывает что иногда один `li` короче другого:

```css
.ul {
    border:1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
.ul > li {
    border:1px solid;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li>Тут какой-то текст</li>
  <li>Тут много текста и еще много много всего</li>
</ul>
```

как их можно выровнять не зависимо от других на одном уровне.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так? Если да, то просто сделать их как элементы таблицы.

```css
.ul {
    border:1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    display: table; /* Все блоки - таблица */
    border-spacing: 5px 0; /* Расстояние между ячейками */
}
li {
    border:1px solid;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align:top;
    display: table-cell; /* Блок - элемент таблицы */
    padding: 5px; /* Отступы текста от границ */
}
.block {
  display: block; /* Для частей, которым не нужно выравнивание */
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li>Тут какой-то текст</li>
  <li>Тут много текста и еще много много всего</li>
  <li class="block">Без выравнивания</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Таблицы фуууууу

Answer (score 1):

Задай ul display:flex

```css
.ul {
    border:1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    display:flex;
}
.ul > li {
    border:1px solid;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li>Тут какой-то текст</li>
  <li>Тут много текста и еще много много всего</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

как подметил @empy26 действительно нужно использовать flexbox.

```css
.ul {
    border:1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
    display:flex;
}
.ul > li {
    border:1px solid;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li>Тут какой-то текст</li>
  <li>Тут много текста и еще много много всего</li>
</ul>
```

Или более кроcсбраузерный на js

```js
equalheight = function(container){

var currentTallest = 0,
     currentRowStart = 0,
     rowDivs = new Array(),
     $el,
     topPosition = 0;
 $(container).each(function() {

   $el = $(this);
   $($el).height('auto')
   topPostion = $el.position().top;

   if (currentRowStart != topPostion) {
     for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
       rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
     }
     rowDivs.length = 0; // empty the array
     currentRowStart = topPostion;
     currentTallest = $el.height();
     rowDivs.push($el);
   } else {
     rowDivs.push($el);
     currentTallest = (currentTallest < $el.height()) ? ($el.height()) : (currentTallest);
  }
   for (currentDiv = 0 ; currentDiv < rowDivs.length ; currentDiv++) {
     rowDivs[currentDiv].height(currentTallest);
   }
 });
}

$(window).load(function() {
  equalheight('.ul li');
});


$(window).resize(function(){
  equalheight('.ul li');
});
```

```css
.ul {
    border:1px solid;
    padding: 10px;
}
.ul > li {
    border:1px solid;
    list-style:none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul">
  <li>Тут какой-то текст</li>
  <li>Тут много текста и еще много много всего</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Главное кроcсбраузерный, но не используя js =)

Comment: чем js не угодил?

Comment: @Duoxx, отключенный JS в браузере все разрушит, верстка такое дело...

Comment: Это да, тогда вынуждайте пользователей обновлять браузер, даже на олдфаговском xp есть chrome 49